# Ant/build.xml functionality ignored since Netbeans 7.1 (for PHP project)

Tags: php, netbeans, ant, build.xml

I used to compress all the JavaScript files in my PHP project automated by an ant file (build.xml). This worked very well until the update to Netbeans 7.1.

Now Netbeans does not recognize this file as an Ant file but as a simple XML file ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgtgF.png))

The build.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myWeb" default="_DEPLOY" basedir=".">
    <target name="minimizeWebFiles" >
        <echo message="Minify!" />
        <exec executable="powershell.exe">
            <arg value="MinimizeWebFiles.ps1" />
        </exec>
        <echo message="End!" />
    </target>
        <target name="_DEPLOY" depends="minimizeWebFiles" />
</project>
```

The same file worked on previous netbeans versions without a problem.

I also know the official manual on [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#build-script), but this does not help. Has anyone an idea, what is wrong here? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that after the netbeans update the "Ant" plugin was not installed!

I don't know why this happened as I had this plugin installed in Netbeans 7.0.

So somehow the update process did not include/installed the Ant plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to Tools->Plugins->Installed tab to see whether your JAVA SE is activated. After you active the option restart your Netbean to take effect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but as you can see above I already found the solution and answered my own question accordingly.